# Summation of infinite series, $\sum((3n+1)^{-1}-(3n+2)^{-1})$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Find the sum of:

> $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{3n+1}- \frac{1}{3n+2}\right) $$

Anwser  given was   $\dfrac{\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}$.

Thanks  in advance.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: Use the Taylor series for $\ln(1-x)$. Let $x$ be the cube roots of unity. Find a way to combine the two series so that it matches your question. (I may supply a full answer later.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{3n+1}- \frac{1}{3n+2}\right)
&=\sum_{m=0}^\infty\left(\int^1_0x^{3n}-x^{3n+1}dx\right)\\
&=\int^1_0\frac{1-x}{1-x^3}dx\\
&=\int^1_0\frac{1}{(x+1/2)^2+3/4}dx\\
&=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\left[\arctan\left(\frac{2x+1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)\right]^1_0\\
&=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\left(\frac{\pi}{3}-\frac{\pi}{6}\right)\\
&=\frac{\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}
\end{align}

Comment: A hint would have been preferable to a full solution.

Comment: How did you get the second step on the RHS from the first step? (I'm just a curious onlooker)

Comment: @taninamdar I swapped the order of summation and integration and summed the terms as a geometric series.

Comment: I still don't exactly get it, can you break it down for me? Also, what are the rules when you can switch summation and integration? Can you provide some link where I can read more about this? Many thanks!

Comment: @taninamdar $x^{3n}-x^{3n+1}$ is non-negative in the interval of integration. You might want to read up on Tonelli's theorem and geometric series. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: consider $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac{e^{2\pi i k/3}}{k}$

Comment: It took me while to understand but gr8 hint. :)